# How to give symfony permisions to write

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I have here a form that is uploading a photo. 
Initially I got an error because symfony couldn't create the direcotry so I created them manualy.

Now I get this error:

```
Unable to write in the "/home/crixi/projects/symfony/src/Acme/TestBundle/Entity/../../../../web/uploads/picture" directory
```

I'm using ubuntu.

Is there any settings that I should to to assign symfony the righs to write in that folder?

Comment: Check as which user and group your webserver runs, check what the current owner & group of the directory is. 2 basic options: you `chown` the directory to the webserver user, or you `chgrp` it to its group and give group read/write/listing permissions on that directory (`g+rwx`).

Comment: strange, apache seems to run on `root`

Comment: ... ev0l.... normally I'd say to fix that first....

Comment: I just fixed it giving write rights for "others" (I know that is not a good ideea, but I'm just in dev mode now so nothing bad can happen I guess). I don't know for what reason even if apache is runing on root, symfony was runing on `others`. Thank you for your help, please post it as a reply to be able to chose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, then your web user will be `www-data`, not `apache`.  So that's why it wouldn't work when you changed the apache permissions.  You can do this properly by doing the following:

1. `sudo chgrp -R www-data /home/crixi/projects/symfony/web/uploads`
2. `sudo chmod -R g+rwx /home/crixi/projects/symfony/web/uploads`

This will allow the web user (`www-data`) the proper permissions to write to your upload dir and subdirs.  This is better than giving everyone write permissions because it's always good to do things right in the dev env so you don't have issues when going to prod.

OR, as @Wrikken suggests, just use `chown` like so:

`sudo chown -R www-data /home/crixi/projects/symfony/web/uploads`

It just depends how you want to manage your permissions.